# Bad request Invalid verb - 400 Error - only in Google chrome

Tags: http-status-code-400

[Invalid verb 400 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MELct.png)

Web site is hosted on IIS. If I browse from browser other than chrome, it is browse able. But in chrome, If I give my ip or even localhost ip (127.0.0.1), this error is coming.

I dont understand why invalid verb error is coming. I m using GET.

Comment: Sometimes it happens due to slow or no internet connection. If the internet is working fine then the token might be invalid.

Comment: Did you find any more info on your bug? I've got a similar issue with a "Unity" WebForms+MVC app on .net 4.0, IIS 7.5.